# How to only get the population per country with World Bank Open Data

Tags: data, population

I try to get the population of every country with an API, but I looked at the [World Bank Open Data](https://data.worldbank.org/) but I can't find just the population of each country.

I looked, and I find lots and lots of data about population with specific criteria like *

> Population in urban agglomerations of more than one million is the
> country's population living in metropolitan areas that in 2018 had a
> population of more than one million people

But I can't find just the population per country.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! If you are looking for open data then opendata.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask

Answer (score -1):

Here's the total population for Canada:

https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL?locations=CA&name_desc=true

And here it is for the United States, Mexico, and Brazil at the same time:

https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL?locations=US-MX-BR&name_desc=true

From the above links you can simply remove the Country and type in a new one to generate the result for Total Population.

Comment: These are the data that I want but is there a way to get them with an API ?